# Getting hour from a datetime field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to retrieve hour from a datetime field. I am running a SOQL query and retrieving a set of values in my apex class and looping through them in my visualforce something like

```
<apex:repeat var="arr" value="{!arrivals}">
```

`{!arr.Pickup_Time__c}` where arrivals is my soql querry in apex which retrieves a set of values.

`Pickup_Time__c` is a datetime field and I want to get only hour out of it.

I don't want to use formula fields as they are other issues of DST, timezone etc.

Can any help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways

1. **Through Visualforce Page:**

`<apex:outputText value="{0,date,HH}">
    <apex:param value="{!arr.Pickup_Time__c}" />
</apex:outputText>`

This will only show you the hour time within the whole datetime.

If you want to specify the condition, you can do like below...

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(VALUE(MID(Text(arr.Pickup_Time__c),12,2))>=12,'PM','AM')}">
</apex:outputText>
```

This will check for the Hour value and based on the value, it will print accordingly. you can use or show the values as per your requirement level.

2. **Through Controller**

---

```
for (YourObject obj: ListofObjectValues) {
    List < Integer > hourTime = new List < Integer > ();
    hourTime.add(obj.Pickup_Time__c.hour());
    for (Integer inte: hourTime) {
        if (inte >= 12 && inte <= 20) {
            System.debug('Do some process');
        } else {
            System.debug('Do another process');
        }
    }
}
```

The choice can be based on your requirement and based on your way of generating your output.
Hope this might helps...

Comment: Thanks Subhash, I did something similar to the controller approach suggested and it works fine.

Comment: The issue with the first approach using visualforce is that it returns the hour in UTC format and it makes things difficult for me as I had to take in to account DST and other things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need **hour()** method of *Datetime*. To get hour of an Datetime field in apex you just need to write;

```
Integer hourOfPickupTime = arr.Pickup_Time__c.hour();
```

**hour()** method returns integer value. For more info on method; [Datetime class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually want to use the hour value for comparison.
Say for ex: if hour value is in between 12 to 20 hours, do something.

Comment: your method should work fine but I am not sure on how to use it when I am inside a loop like this :<apex:repeat var="arr" value="{!arrivals}">